# Conditional onClick from ternary

Tags: reactjs, ternary

I'm trying to have an onClick event fire depending on the location of the user.
if the location is '/favorites' i want to return null i've tried using a ternary operator to achieve this, and cannot find my mistake.  heres what i've tried:

```
             {this.props.location==='/favorites' ? null : 
                onClick={() => {
                    this.props.updateFavsState(this.props.character);
                    this.setState(prevState => ({
                      loved: !prevState.loved
                    }));
                  }}
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put logic in the function and call function onClick event, location pass to the function as argument.

Solution:

```
handleClick = (location) => {
  if (location === '/favorites') {
    return null;
 }
  this.props.updateFavsState(this.props.character);
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    loved: !prevState.loved
  });
}

// somewhere in your render component
onClick={() => { handleClick(this.props.location)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is

```
onClick={this.props.location==='/favorites' ? null : 
   () => {
      this.props.updateFavsState(this.props.character);
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          loved: !prevState.loved
      }));
}}
```