# Multiple functions inside onClick with a ternary and reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This is an example of something I'd like to understand better syntactically in JSX.

### Problem:

This works:

```js
<button
  onClick={ !isRecording ? beginRecording : endRecording } > 
</button>
```

and this works:

```js
<button
  onClick={ () => { modalPortal.current.open() } } > 
</button>

<Modal ref={modalPortal}>
    <h1>Congratulations!</h1> 
    <p>If this modal opened, you find javascript syntax seamless and intuitive</p>
</Modal>
```

Together, no bueno.

```js
<button
    onClick={!isRecording ? () => {modalPortal.current.open();beginRecording} : endRecording } > 
</button>
```

### Error:

> **react-expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression**

---

### Detail:

This is inside a function component. `isRecording` & `endRecording` etc are are states in an object within the scope of the function component which defines the page I'm on in the app, `modalPortal` is a reference:

```js
export default function RecordPage() 
{
    let [audioURL, isRecording, beginRecording, endRecording, timer] = RecorderContext(); 
    const modalPortal = useRef(null);
...
}
```

I've also tried various permutations of passing this out to a single function that does the conditional evaluation etc

```js
onClick={ doManyThings() } >
```

With and without arrows, both kinds of brackets and passing in arguments and without, none of it seems to work. I'd love a clear answer from someone knowledgeable!

---

**References to things I've tried that don't work:**

[Conditional onClick from ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192066/conditional-onclick-from-ternary)

[Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs)

[Setting conditional onClick behaviour in React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627838/setting-conditional-onclick-behaviour-in-react-component)

[React: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573277/react-expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression)

Comment: Use `beginRecording()` and `endRecording()` if you're going to use the second syntax. You can't mix and match function calls and function references like that. Or, just have a function that encapsulates the ternary and stop doing conditional logic in the views.

Comment: You just need to do `onClick={ () => doManyThings() }`

Comment: @Yadab - tried that - no,  it was indeed the missing brackets. I'm yet to understand why it's syntactically valid to drop them in one context and cryptically halt the compiler in another

Comment: A function name is just a reference to that function, i.e. `doManyThings`, and when you add the parenthesis, `doManyThings()`, you are invoking that function. `onClick={doManyThings}` is very nearly a functional equivalent to `onClick={() => doManyThings()}`. In many cases in React you'll see the parens dropped for a couple reasons: (1) the onClick callback doesn't care about the click event, and (2) the callback doesn't need to be passed any arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the ternary/branching logic *into* a single callback function.

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    if (!isRecording) {
      modalPortal.current.open();
      beginRecording();
    } else {
      endRecording();
    }
  }
>
  ...
</button>
```

If you want to continue using the ternary though you need to also invoke the `beginRecording` function. The idea is similar here, based on the condition, return an anonymous function that does a couple things, or return a function reference that does whatever *it* does.

```
<button
  onClick={!isRecording 
    ? () => {
        modalPortal.current.open();
        beginRecording(); // <-- also invoke
      } 
    : endRecording
  } 
>
  ... 
</button>
```

Comment: Drew, I could kiss you. I've damn near thrown my laptop out the window over the last two hours. This well-voted answer (that suggests only ternaries can be used) was **very** misleading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45573716/12137312

Comment: Ahh appreciate the edit to add more context to the answer.

Comment: what I find infuriating is the the difference here between success and failure in the attempt I proposed is literally the brackets added to the function call. Just adding brackets to `beginRecording()` fixes it.

Comment: @lys Interestingly enough, that other answer seems to address the linting warning/error, but it seems to be answering a different question/issue. To me it seems the mention of ternaries was an afterthought, but either way, I can see where that might lead you astray if you didn't realize what is implicitly returned for each case still needs to be valid by its own merit.

Comment: @lys Right, syntax can be tricky (and important!) like that. 

Comment: I'm all for it! Thanks for providing insight. I guess the real issue here is not really comprehending the compiler error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  if (isRecording) {
    endRecording()
    return
  }

  modalPortal.current.open()
  beginRecording()
}


<button onClick={handleButtonClick} />
```